# Como corrigir erro na conexão num site?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli

Atualmente administro o [site de uma Prefeitura](http://www.afogadosdaingazeira.pe.gov.br), e hoje, do nada, começou a aparecer o seguinte erro:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: Headers and
>   client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50521 Library:50639 in
>   /home/afoga205/public_html/var_ini.php on line 174

A linha em questão está sendo essa:

```
    $this->conexao = mysqli_connect($_host['host'],$database['username'],$database['password']) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Qual a solução pra resolver esse problema?

Comment: A versão do MySQL com a qual seu PHP foi compilado está diferente da versão da biblioteca MySQL que está sendo utilizada. Você atualizou um dos dois recentemente?

Comment: Não, atualizei não.O site está hospedado no HostGator e notei hoje que alguns layouts foram atualizados, mas não recebi nenhuma informação sobre atualização do MySQL ou outra coisa.

Comment: Então é um caso pra se ver com o suporte da HostGator, já que a hospedagem é deles. Mas o erro é provavelmente esse que falei.

Comment: De fato, eu ainda não havia procurado solução com eles. Vou averiguar e darei um retorno.

Comment: @RenatoDiniz, estou passando aqui pra dizer que realmente era um problema no servidor da HostGator. Foi resolvido assim que abri o ticket.

Obrigado!